# Inquire POS returns very large integers in Fortran

Tags: io, fortran

I am reading and writing huge files, using unformatted form and stream access.
During the running, I open the same file multiple times, and I read only portions of the file that I need in that moment. I have huge files in order to avoid writing too many smaller files on the hard-disk. I don't read these huge files all in once because they are too large and I would have memory problems.

In order to read only portions of the files, I do this. Let's say that I have written the array A(1:10) on a file "data.dat", and let's say that I need to read it twice in an array B(1:5). This is what I do

```
real, dimension(5) :: B
integer:: fu, myposition

open(newunit=fu,file="data.dat",status="old",form = 'unformatted',access='stream')
read (fu,POS=1) B
inquire(unit=fu,POS=myposition)
close(fu)

[....]

open(newunit=fu,file="data.dat",status="old",form = 'unformatted',access='stream')
read (fu,POS=myposition) B
inquire(unit=fu,POS=myposition)
close(fu)

[...]
```

My questions are:

1. Is this approach correct?
2. When the files are too big, the inquire(fu,POS=myposition) goes wrong,
   because the integer is too big (indeed, I get negative values).
   Should I simply declare the integer myposition as a larger integer?
   Or there is a better way to do what I am trying to do.
   In other words, having such a huge integers is related to the fact that I am using a very clumsy approach?

P.S.
To be more quantitative, this is the order of magnitude: I have thousands of files of around 10 giga each.

Comment: Most compilers support more than one integer kind type parameter.  With gfortran, you can to `integer(8)` to get a 64-bit signed integer.  PS: you only need to open the file once and leave it open.

Comment: Don't use explicit Integers for kinds. For portability reasons it's better to `Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only : int64` and then `Integer( int64 ) :: ...` . Remember constants also need a kind if it is not the default, e.g. `1_int64`.

Comment: It would help your question if you quantify "huge" and "too big"

Comment: What happens if `int64` is -1?